# Azure SQL MI storage space alert

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-alerts, sql-azure-alerts

I want to create an alert on azure SQL MI if storage space is used more than 80%.But not found any condition on storage space used percentage. Image is attched that shows available options to set alert

[image: Image is attached for reference available options]

1. How can I set an alert on Azure SQLMI on storage used more thn 80%
2. The value 250.48 k relates to which value in the stats table below
   what is this metrics is showing
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/alerts-create?view=azuresql)  below are the available options to create alerts in SQL managed instance.

[image]

So, there is no direct way to create alert to when SQL MI storage is greater than 80%. You can follow below procedure to get alert:

Enable diagnostic settings in SQL managed instance as mentioned below:

[image]

Create log search alert in log analytics workspace with below query:

```
AzureMetrics
| extend p = pack(MetricName, Average)
| summarize bag = make_bag(p) by TimeGenerated
| evaluate bag_unpack(bag)
| extend reserved_storage = reserved_storage_mb
| extend used_storage = storage_space_used_mb
| extend storage_used_percentage = round(100.0 * used_storage / reserved_storage)
| project TimeGenerated, storage_used_percentage, reserved_storage, used_storage
| where storage_used_percentage >= 80
```

As mentioned in below image:

[image]

You will be able to get alert when SQL MI storage is greater than 80%. For more information you can refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359387/how-to-setup-alert-on-azure-sql-mi-instance-for-storage-space-used).

Comment: when I create a log search alert with the above provided query it gives error : 'extend' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'reserved_storage_mb'

Request id: 427bfdbe-0b57-48ed-a224-39a16545a72e 
https://ibb.co/VLCdLW9



@Bhavani

Comment: Once try with values instead of 'reserved_storage_mb' and  'storage_space_used_mb' like mentioned in above image.

Comment: https://ibb.co/SsKsv7h


No result found

Comment: I am also looking to create space alert in % for SQL MI. but no luck