# How can I set up alerts in Azure for SQL Managed Instance when storage exceeds 80% capacity?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, alerts, azure-sql-managed-instance

I'm working with Azure SQL Managed Instance and I'm looking to configure alerts to notify me when the storage usage reaches or exceeds 80% capacity. Could someone provide guidance or steps on how to achieve this within Azure's monitoring or alerting system?

I've explored Azure's monitoring options but haven't found a clear way to set up these specific alerts.

Comment: could you share what you've try so far ? it s pretty straight forward from the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/alerts-insights-configure-portal?view=azuresql

Comment: We are trying to set an alert Storage space used by the Azure SQL-MI

1- I have tried creating an alert through metrices storage space used but it does not provide us with the exact storage space used value.

2- I created Log Analytics and sending the MI logs to it, and tried to run custom queries to create an alert but no luck so far.

Comment: Is there a way we can Add an alert on Storage used by MI on Percentage basis?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/alerts-create?view=azuresql), the available options to create alerts in SQL Managed Instance are shown below:

[image: Available options for alerts]

There is no direct way to create an alert when SQL MI storage is greater than 80%. However, you can follow the procedure below to get an alert:

1. Enable diagnostic settings in SQL Managed Instance as shown below:

[image: Diagnostic settings]

2. Create a log search alert in the Log Analytics workspace with the following query:

```
AzureMetrics
| extend p = pack(MetricName, Average)
| summarize bag = make_bag(p) by TimeGenerated
| evaluate bag_unpack(bag)
| extend reserved_storage = reserved_storage_mb
| extend used_storage = storage_space_used_mb
| extend storage_used_percentage = round(100.0 * used_storage / reserved_storage)
| project TimeGenerated, storage_used_percentage, reserved_storage, used_storage
| where storage_used_percentage >= 80
```

3. Set up the alert as shown in the image below:

[image: Log search alert]

You will receive an alert when SQL MI storage is greater than 80%. For more information, refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359387/how-to-setup-alert-on-azure-sql-mi-instance-for-storage-space-used).

Comment: I am trying the above query but it gives an error : 'extend' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'reserved_storage_mb'

Comment: Once try with values instead of 'reserved_storage_mb' and 'storage_space_used_mb' like mentioned in above image.

Comment: It is not showing any results, I added values with respect to my SQL-MI specs.